# HQL SUM Query - unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I can execute an HQL as follows:

```
select order.anticipatedMonetaryTotal.payableAmount.value from OrderType order
```

using a code like:

```
EntityManager e = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
e.getTransaction().begin();
result = e.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

So, I know that the `order.anticipatedMonetaryTotal.payableAmount.value` is a correct location to fetch values (a list of BigDecimal values).

However, I'm getting a:

```
line 1:14: unexpected token: order
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: order
```

for the following query:

```
select SUM ( order.anticipatedMonetaryTotal.payableAmount.value) from OrderType order
```

So, what do I miss about the SUM notation? As far as I can see at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation, it is quite straightforward and I cannot see any mistake in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not because of SUM function, this is because of `order` word. This is reserved word which cannot be used for variables. Change it on something other e.g. orderType

```
select SUM ( orderType.anticipatedMonetaryTotal.payableAmount.value) from OrderType orderType
```

This should solve your issue, because everything else is fine.

Good luck.